# Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null : Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using provider from flutter and building an application.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/providers/products.dart';

import 'product_item.dart';

class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = productsData.items;
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[index],
        child: ProductItem(),
      ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting following exception.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ProductItem file:///D:/code/flutter/shop_app/lib/widgets/products_grid.dart:17:16
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 3 of 546 libraries in 378ms.
```

Comment: It looks like you have a null boolean value in `Products` class.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Thank you